# Interpretation de « connaissance de base réseau »

Tags: adjectifs, noms, constructions

J'ai un problème d’interprétation pour l'expression suivante (et plus généralement des constructions similaires).

> Connaissance de base réseau

Est-ce que je dois interpréter la phrase comme: « Connaissance de base » dans le domaine du réseau, ou est-ce que ça veut dire: connaissance dans le domaine de « base réseau » (et si c'est le dernier, c'est quoi un « base réseau » ?)

Comment: Quel est le contexte ? Un CV ? Je lirais « Connaissances de bases en réseau » (avec mon domaine personnel, il s'agit de réseaux en informatiques, routeur, switchs, administration réseau etc.).

Comment: `base réseau` n'existe pas, C'est plutôt des connaissances de base dans le domaine du réseau.

Comment: @comethapaxd'ajax -- *Réseautique* n'est pas un mot qui déborde des claviers spécialisés :  est-ce qu'il s'agit de construire des réseaux, qui sont des assemblages complexes de technologies variées, est-ce qu'il s'agit des langages employés, est-ce un concept "super global" comme bureautique ??? Le jugement de Ngram https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=r%C3%A9seau%2C+r%C3%A9seautique&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cr%C3%A9seau%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cr%C3%A9seautique%3B%2Cc0 est sans appel !

Comment: @comethapaxd'ajax -- Les sens acceptés au Canada ne sont pas du tout entrés dans les usages de l'hexagone, et je n'ai jamais entendu ce mot prononcé par l'équipe réseau de l'entreprise, ni ne l'ai lu dans leurs études de marché. D'où ma réponse à la question de votre commentaire précédent. Les mots mettent parfois plusieurs années à traverser l'Atlantique, d'habitude les mots techniques arrivent les premiers, mais il semble que ce ne soit pas le cas pour celui-là. On parle plutôt de *sous-réseau*, de *réseau dédié*.

Comment: @comethapaxd'ajax J'ai découvert une définition : http://www.igt.net/~ngrenon/UdeM/cours/INF3270/Notes%20de%20cours/chap1.pdf page 2, *N.B. le site est à Montréal* ; jusqu'à présent je n'avais entendu parlé que de *télématique*, d'*Internet* et de *téléinformatique*. Et cela ne correspond pas du tout à ce que j'avais cru comprendre dans la définition de FranceTerme, par exemple, en France on parle de *domotique* pour ce qui est représenté par l'expression *réseautique domestique*.

Answer (score 3):

Écrit comme cela, c'est sujet à plusieurs interprétations.
En ajoutant « : » cela donne :

> Connaissance de base : réseau

Cela signifie que les connaissances de base sont : « le réseau » et d'autres éventuellement.

Answer (score 3):

Je dirais « Connaissances de base en réseau ».

Comment: Oui je suis d'accord. Mais comment dois-je interpreter la phrase alors?

Comment: Quelque chose comme : *J'ai des connaissances de base (en) / (dans le domaine du) réseau*

Answer (score 3):

Il est vrai que la rédaction de la phrase est incorrecte, style télégraphique qui doit être proche de l'anglais ou de l'américain mal assimilé.

Pour l'interprétation "de base réseau", le pluriel s'impose :

> Connaissances des bases réseau(x)

... en supposant qu'il existe plusieurs types de bases dédiées au réseau.
Le (x) est optionnel selon que les bases gère un ou plusieurs types de réseau.

L'interprétation intuitive, dans un contexte de C.V. :

> - Connaissance de base : réseau
> - Connaissance systèmes : infocentres,  ....

Comment: Les bases comme l'_abc_ si je comprends bien dans ce premier exemple. J'ai rédigé une réponse suite à notre échange ; n'hésitez pas à rapporter vos commentaires sous celle-ci. Merci !

Answer (score 0):

> J'ai des amis en réseau qui travaillent en réseau à mettre en réseau,
>   avec leurs connaissances de base réseau, les bases réseaux d'un
>   réseau... d'entreprise.

Je partage votre désarroi, et vous pouvez imaginer d'emblée le même genre de difficulté dans le domaine du traitement de l'*information* et de l'*électron*. Plus sérieusement, dans votre exemple, il s'agit fort certainement de *connaissances de base*. On parle par métonymie d'*avoir, acquérir, amasser des [connaissances](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/connaissance) + adj[ectif] + dans, en, sur + subst[antif]* (TLFi) ; [de base](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/base/8184/locution?q=de%20base#168513), c'est-à-dire *fondamentales* ou *essentielles* (Larousse). Plus simplement, ce sont des [*notions*](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/notion), ces *connaissance[s] d'ensemble, élémentaire[s], acquise[s] de quelque chose* (TLFi). D'autre part, on aurait pu parler d'une connaissance *des* réseaux, ou *du* réseau comme concept (*avoir, posséder la (une bonne) connaissance de qqc.*, TLFi), sauf qu'on préférerait savoir desquels parce que le nom [réseau](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/r%C3%A9seau) dépasse le cadre du *réseau informatique* ou *d'ordinateurs*. L'informatique n'étant pas mon domaine, je ne spéculerai pas sur ce qui est d'usage dans tel ou tel milieu. Évidemment, dans le C.V. d'un(e) informaticien(ne) l'idée du *réseau* reste sans doute bien claire et distincte, et on s'appuie sur ce contexte à mon avis pour parler d'un domaine d'expertise.

---

Un commentaire au sujet du lexique et de la terminologie. Le suffixe [*-ique*](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/-ique) peut s'appliquer à un substantif non suffixé (comme avec *argotique*) ; *réseautique* est possible ([FranceTerme](http://www.culture.fr/franceterme/result?francetermeSearchTerme=r%C3%A9seautique&francetermeSearchDomaine=0&francetermeSearchSubmit=rechercher&action=search), [GDT](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8369045), [Termium](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-eng.html?lang=eng&i=1&srchtxt=r%C3%A9seautique&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs)). Le terme me semble utile parce que ça permet d'éviter la confusion avec *mettre/la mise en réseau*, ainsi qu'avec l'idée d'adjectif épithète, car ces connaissances n'ont pas la qualité d'un réseau, ou encore avec le genre d'amalgame dont vous traitez comme *la base réseau*. D'autre part, le suffixe *-ique* a la valeur de « qui est propre à » et m'apparaît personnellement plus utile, parce que plus précis, que d'employer le mot *réseau* par métonymie pour les techniques servant à exploiter des réseaux d'ordinateurs.